# Formatting two columns with dollar signs during to_csv using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a csv merge that has many columns. I am having trouble formatting price columns.I need to have them follow this format $1,000.00.Is there a function I can use to achieve this for just two columns (Sales Price and Payment Amount)? Here is my code so far:

```
    df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='left', on=['Org ID', 'Org Name'])
    cols = ['Org Name', 'Org Type', 'Chapter', 'Join Date', 'Effective Date', 'Expire Date', 
'Transaction Date', 'Product Name', 'Sales Price',  
            'Invoice Code', 'Payment Amount', 'Add Date']
    df3 = df3[cols]
    df3 = df3.fillna("-")
    out_csv = root_out + "report-merged.csv"
    df3.to_csv(out_csv, index=False)
```

A solution that I thought was going to work but I get an error **(ValueError: Unknown format code 'f' for object of type 'str')**

```
df3['Sales Price'] = df3['Sales Price'].map('${:,.2f}'.format)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your error (`"Unknown format code 'f' for object of type 'str'"`), the columns that you are trying to format are being treated as strings.  So using `.astype(float)` in the code below addresses this.

There is not a great way to set this formatting *during* (within) your `to_csv` call.  However, in an intermediate line you could use:

```
cols = ['Sales Price', 'Payment Amount']
df3.loc[:, cols] = df3[cols].astype(float).applymap('${:,.2f}'.format)
```

Then call `to_csv`.